# How to go back to previous scroll place when navigation to go back?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got a `productList page` and `product details` page

In the product list page I got a `scroll handler`  on the flatList which load more data when the end of the list is reached.

The ***`product list`*** component is something like this

```
let productList = useSelector(state => state.productReducer.productList);

const [numbersOfItem, setNumberOfItem] = useState(20);
const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(productList);


const handleLoadMoreData = async () => {
        setLoadingMoreData(true);
        try {
            let requestNumber = numbersOfItem + 20;
            setNumberOfItem(requestNumber);
            await dispatch(
                fetchProductList(
                    categoryTitle,
                    subCategoryName,
                    activeTab,
                    requestNumber,
                ),
            );
        } catch {
            console.log('error');
        } finally {
            setLoadingMoreData(false);
        }
    };

<FlatList
    data={itemList}
    numColumns={2}
    nestedScrollEnabled
    columnWrapperStyle={styles.flatItemColumn}
    scrollEnabled
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    snapToAlignment="start"
    decelerationRate={'fast'}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    renderItem={renderIndividualItem}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
    onEndReached={() => handleLoadMoreData()}
/>
```

After Scrolling for a while when I see a product I wanna explore I will goes into the `product details` page

Inside the `product details` page when I click `navigation.goBack()`.
The scroll position in the `productList` is go back to the place of `20th item`. I think its because the default display is `setNumberOfItem` is set to 20.

How can I change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an Api Call in a focus callBack in the screen that you want to go back to, can help solve this problem.(ProductList)

```
   React.useEffect(() => {
          fetchData();//func to get the data
          const willFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            fetchData();//call it here as well
        });

        return willFocusSubscription;
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the[initialScrollIndex](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialScrollIndex) prop of the `FlatList` component to order the index where you want to start the FlatList. And find out how to know from which screen you come from when your productList page get focused